# Где на ruSO есть прямая ссылка на data.stackexchange.com?

Tags: поддержка, data-explorer

А есть где-нибудь на ruSO или мете прямая ссылка на data.stackexchange.com?

Название сайта вылетает из головы, а пользуюсь я им от силы раз в пол года. Каждый раз, когда нужно написать какой-нибудь запрос, приходится здесь на мете искать посты с запросами и потом уже переходить на сайт.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

внизу каждой страницы есть столбец со ссылками «stack exchange network»:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если развернуть (нажав на кнопку со стрелкой вправо) последний пункт («other»), то можно увидеть ссылку, озаглавленную «data»:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

она ведёт именно на https://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Футер недавно претерпел изменения.